# Server returns content-type application/x-httpd-php5 instead of application/json

Tags: php, json, apache, mime-types, content-type

My PHP code returns a JSON string and sets to the response header `Content-Type: application/json`.

On localhost it works fine, it just returns the JSON string I passed. But, request to the remote server, on my browser network/header, the content type is `application/x-httpd-php5`. And the content, before the json string, it prints the texts in the `std-output` and that header string:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.8

Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate

Date: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 02:49:36 GMT

Content-Type: application/json

pragma: no-cache

expires: -1

X-Debug-Token: 187f4e
```

after that I get the json string I sent.

The PHP version of my PC and the hosting is PHP 7.2. I use Apache. The hosting supposed too. But, from the browser response header, I see `Server: nginx`.

From the server into Mime types, I got application/json -> json. I uploaded a .json file, I got `Content-Type: application/json`. I set to my .htaccess file

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddType 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' .json
```

but still nothing changes.

I don't know why on my localhost I got `Content-Type: application/json` but on the hosting I got `application/x-httpd-php5`.

Here is the raw Response:

```
HTTP/2.0 200 OK
server: nginx
date: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 03:31:45 GMT
content-type: application/x-httpd-php5
cache-control: max-age=0
expires: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 03:31:44 GMT
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

Comment: In addition to `AddType`, have you tried: `AddHandler application/json .json`?

Comment: I added it on top of my .htaccess file:

 `AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddType 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' .json
AddHandler application/json .json`

But still nothing

Comment: I added the raw response using HTTP/2.0 to the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP prints out a buffer string into web-page on certain circuntances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51869375/php-prints-out-a-buffer-string-into-web-page-on-certain-circuntances)